# Magento2: How can enable all input type of product attribute after attribute save?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to update product attribute input type from dropdown to multiselect but only there are three option available (dropdown, text swatch and visual swatch).

[image]

I have searched for that and found only custom script for specific attribute input type's update. Anyone have an idea for that if we can do by magento files for enabling all options always.

Comment: @Amit Bera, Can you please suggest for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi, instead of doing a lot of code.

The best idea  to follow the below process:

> 1. Export a Product Csv  from Magento export/Import section  with     column **store, website,SKU,yourDropattribute**
> 2. Create a new attribute of multi-select type and assign same options
>      of current dropdown attribute
> 3. Assign this new attribute to the same attributes set which drop-down attribute.
> 4. Now import your exported CSV with changes column  `yourDropattribute`    to `yourNewMulitSelectAttribute`.
> 5. After import completed, changes switch `attribute_code` value
>      between    your old drop-down attribute and new multi-select at
>      **eav_attribute    dATABASE table**  using MySQL query.
> 6. After that Do the indexing commands line.